# Laravel: how to use @lang within {{ }}

Tags: laravel

Sorry for what should be a basic question, but I'm tearing my hair out on this.  In Laravel I am constructing a form control using:

```
{{ Form::select('prefix', [
    'null' => '-select-', 
    'Ms.' => 'Ms.', 
    'Mr.' => 'Mr.'
]) }}
```

This works fine.  Now, I want to use multi-language for the displayed names, for example:

```
@lang('prefix.null')
```

The multi-language also works fine, but combining it within the above request is creating parsing errors:

```
{{ Form::select('prefix', [
    'null' => @lang('prefix.null'), 
    'Ms.' => 'Ms.', 
    'Mr.' => 'Mr.'
]) }}
```

Presumably because I need to somehow escape {{ }} to retrieve the @lang string.  I've tried a number of variations, but with no luck so far.

Any assistance greatly appreciated (sorry for the 101 question!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`__()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-__) helper:

```
'null' => __('prefix.null'),
```

Or the [`trans()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-trans) helper:

```
'null' => trans('prefix.null'),
```

Comment: Thank you!  The __() helper seems to choke, the page renders part way then halts.  trans() works perfectly though.  Many thanks for your kind help